# Calculate vector of an object aligned to another object in a 3D envorionment

Tags: vectors, 3d

I have an object (100x100x5) with given coordinates and angles. Now I want to place another object aligned to the left/right side of the "original" object. On the X-Axis I need to substract/add 100, but how do I calculate the Y coordinate?

A basic, not 100% proportional correct, image to visualize of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: https://s22.postimg.org/dmutvczip/vector.png]

Comment: Two questions: are the coordinates for the left lower corner of the object? Is the angle $y=75$ the angle between the lower edge and the horizontal line?

Comment: @KittyL The coordinates for the object would be in the bottom center of the object. I am not sure what the answer to your second question is. The angle is the direction in which the object is facing. I should have written "Pitch, Yaw, Roll" instead of x, y, z.